# Session is working perfectly on browser but not in IIS server in ASHX files

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, web-config, ashx

Here I want to set and get back the session value of Layer. 
My browser can manipulate it smoothly but it is not operating in the same way after hosting it in server. I have attached my ASHX file and the web configuration.

ASHX File:

```
public class ussd : IHttpHandler,IRequiresSessionState
    {                        

        int LayerNo = 0;
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            LayerNo = Convert.ToInt32(context.Session["layer"]);
            LayerNo++;

            HttpContext.Current.Session["layer"] = LayerNo;
            context.Response.Write(LayerNo);
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Web Configuration:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="" cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" timeout="90">
 </sessionState>
```

Comment: You are using both `HttpContext.Current.Sesssion` and `context.Session`. Try using only `context.Session`.

Comment: I have made necessary changes and used only context.Session but it is still not working on the IIS server. After hosting it on Server, it release the previous session for new URL request. 
Is there any issue with the Server Session State mode settings or cookie settings which may conflict with my web configuration?

Comment: Since Session is available now, could it this be an issue with the logic in the code?